# WP REST API can't set post tags

Tags: wordpress

I create post with WP REST API but can't set tags for the post.

```
var post_data = {
    'author': 1,
    'title': 'My title',
    'content': 'My content',
    'status': 'publish',
    'tags': ['tags1','tags2'],
}
```

That code return error: `Invalid parameter(s): tags`

Can you explain wheres wrong?